# How IN clause is working in this sub query

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

```
SELECT branch
  FROM branch_m
 WHERE subbranch IN (SELECT subbranch FROM branch_s)
```

this query returns all records from `BRANCH_M` table
whereas subbranch column is not present in `BRANCH_S` table

table `BRANCH_M` have columns `(ID, BRANCH, SUBBRANCH)`
table `BRANCH_S` have columns `(SID, DEPT)`

```
BRANCH_M
ID, BRANCH, SUBBRANCH
10  Engg    CS
10  Engg    ME
20  Mtech   EE

BRANCH_S
SID, DEPT
1    CS
2    IS
```

when I run the query, the output is

```
BRANCH
Engg
Engg
Mtech
```

could you please explain this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very common mistake when using subqueries.
If there is no `subbranch` column in `branch_s` then Oracle looks up that column in the outer query.
So the query becomes:

```
SELECT branch 
FROM branch_m 
WHERE branch_m.subbranch IN (SELECT branch_m.subbranch FROM branch_s)
```

And the `where` condition evaluates to true (except for cases when the `branch_s` table is empty or `branch_m.subbranch` contains nulls - that's a different quirk).
To avoid this problem *always* use aliases:

```
SELECT m.branch 
FROM branch_m m
WHERE m.subbranch IN (SELECT s.subbranch FROM branch_s s)
```

This way you will get the error right away if there is no `subbranch` in `branch_s`, instead of a seemingly working but wrong query.
Always you aliases, they will save you from a lot of headache.